# Unity3D third party C# library inclusion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state, nuget-package

So I'm currently working on making an RPG that's going to require a lot of state machines with Unity3D. The problem I'm running into is when trying to include the Stateless Framework http://nuget.org/packages/Stateless/ in my project, the framework is removed each time I close Unity.

Is there a special method for including C# libraries like this in Unity, or is it simply not allowed?

Comment: Are you using visual studio or monodevelop or what? You'll have to include the library in the IDE and sync from within Unity. Also, you might have better luck getting answers on http://answers.unity3d.com/

Comment: I'm using visual studio. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

The best thing you can do is write a C# Library that handles this and place it in the plugin folder in the inspector (you have to create it yourself)

Create a library with a public class and reference them directly in C#
every library that is included in the Plugin folder will automatically be included
in your unity scripts.

Comment: Could you please provide an example ?